# Why do module doctests stop working when there are module variables?

Tags: python, doctest

Take the following example.  Why does uncommenting that line on the top cause the doctest to stop working?

```
#a = 3 # Uncommenting this line causes the doctest to stop working

"""
>>> factorial(5)
10
"""

def factorial(n):
    import math
    if not n >= 0:
        raise ValueError("n must be >= 0")
    if math.floor(n) != n:
        raise ValueError("n must be exact integer")
    if n+1 == n:  # catch a value like 1e300
        raise OverflowError("n too large")
    result = 1
    factor = 2
    while factor <= n:
        result *= factor
        factor += 1
    return result


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()
```

Comment: I'm honestly perplexed. (Following in case someone else figures it out.) Suggestion: you don't need the function for this [mre]. A doctest as simple as `>>> 5` -> `10` or even `>>> True` -> `False` should fail when run, with no extra code needed.

Comment: It doesn't seem that global variables are the issue, exactly. Put `a = 3` *after* the doctest, and the doctest still runs as expected. On the other hand, a simple value (like `3`) or a function call (like `print()`) at the top of the file both exhibit the same test-skipping behavior. I'm at a loss as to why.